# Define auto-scaling policy for AWS EKS Nodegroups in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I approached with managed node groups (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html) option. It was working. But how to define the autoscaling policy. It just allows giving max and min node counts not even name.

```
  BatchJobNodeGroup:
Type: 'AWS::EKS::Nodegroup'
Properties:
  ClusterName: !Ref EksCluster
  CapacityType: !Ref NodeCapacityType
  DiskSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
  AmiType: !Ref AmiType
  InstanceTypes: [!Ref NodeInstanceType]
  NodeRole:
    "Fn::GetAtt": ["EKSIAMRole", "Arn"]
  ScalingConfig:
    MinSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
    DesiredSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
    MaxSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
  Labels:
    NodeGroup: BatchJobNodeGroup
  Subnets:
    - !Ref PrivateSubnet01
    - !Ref PrivateSubnet02
```

In ScalingConfig also I'm not able to pass any extra args.

Comment: Virtual node groups don't scale themselves, you need something like the [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler).

Comment: @jordanm It works. Thank you